# Pushing a values in a Particular format to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, rickshaw

I want to create an array dynamically which should be having a value in the format of

```
var dat1 = [
    { x: 0, y: 32.07  },
    { x: 1, y: 37.69  },
    { x: 2, y: 529.49 },
    { x: 3, y: 125.49 },
    { x: 4, y: 59.04  }
];
```

I want to store the whole thing in data into an array dynamically. I am getting these values from the json data. And I want an array to be in this format. How can I create it?

I tried this:

```
$.each(r_data, function(key, val) {
    data1.push([{
        x : i,
        y : parseFloat(val.something)
    }]);
    i++;        
});
```

...but didn't get the result I wanted.

Comment: What is the problem? Pushing an _object_?

Comment: Is `322` meant to be `32`? What do you want here? Floor the numbers?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agree. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Ash: I took the liberty of editing the question to add back some information from the old version. Please re-edit if I've re-introduced something incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have

```
var data1 = [];
```

...and probably

```
var i = 0;
```

...prior to your code, your code will produce this structure:

```
var data1 = [
    [ { x: 0, y: 32.07  } ],
    [ { x: 1, y: 37.69  } ],
    [ { x: 2, y: 529.49 } ],
    [ { x: 3, y: 125.49 } ],
    [ { x: 4, y: 59.04  } ]
];
```

Note how you've ended up with an array where each entry is *another* array, which in turn contains the object with the `x` and `y` properties.

I suspect you want:

```
var data1 = [];
var i = 0;
$.each(resultBar_data, function(key, value) {
    data1.push({
        x : i,
        y : parseFloat(value.averagePrice)
    });
    i++;        
});
```

...which just pushes the objects directly on `data1`, without wrapping them in extra arrays (note I've removed the `[]` around what's being pushed). You would access those entries like this:

```
console.log("The first entry is "  + data1[0].x + "," + data1[0].y);
console.log("The second entry is " + data1[1].x + "," + data1[1].y);
```

Comment: @Ash: My *"But I suspect you meant"* code does what the updated question asks.

Answer (score 0):

format is an array of objects. In your following code, you are trying to push *an array* `[{x:i, y:parseFloat(value.averagePrice)}]` to the format array:

```
$.each(resultBar_data, function(key, value) {
    format.push([{ /*array start*/
        x : i,
        y : parseFloat(value.averagePrice)
    }] /*array end*/
    );
    i++;        
    });
```

Remember square brackets denote an array.

I think to fix your problem it should be:

```
/*i just removed the square brackets so that push now pushes an object, 
not an array with a single object*/
format.push({ 
        x : i,
        y : parseFloat(value.averagePrice)
    });
```

Hope this helps, please ask if you need more information or if I misunderstood your question!